# I want to edit two different text files using another text file

Tags: linux

I want to edit one text file, and it will automatically edited another text files.
Is this possible? For example I have three save text files namely fileA.txt, fileB.txt
 and fileC.txt

I just want to edit fileC.txt and some of the chosen data will also save in the two other files.. I dont know if this is possible. I am just a new linux user. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are the three files the same to start with?

Comment: Do you have a preferred editor? Vim's 'scrollbind' and 'cursorbind' options might get you part way toward a solution.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want all of the files to be the same when you are finished? Perhaps `ln` or `ln -s` is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to edit fileC.txt and ***some of the chosen data*** will also
>   save in the two other files.

I'm not sure if you can do that right away from a/the text editor, but maybe you can set up a script to run after your edit, something like:

```
grep "value you want to save in the other files" C.txt >> A.txt
grep "value you want to save in the other files" C.txt >> B.txt
```

If this is not what you meant, please provide a full example (edit your question with it) of what will be your input, and your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a comment to Jim's answer but my rep is not high enough, apologize for writing this as a separate answer.

Agreed, this is not something you can do in vi.  You would need to script something in place.  If you give us a specific example, I'm sure a lot of us here will be able to give you a more meaningful answer.

As it is, you would need to do something like

1) edit file

2) run script that distributes edits to all other files